# I can't reach my page on localhost when I define a new variable on my app.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLdOJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgD0e.png)

Hi,
When I try to define the variable const items = [];
My localhost refuse to connect. I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. or (This site can't be reached).
When I comment out the the line where I've declared the variable, the site works.

Does anybody have an idea about why?

My firewall is off and I disabled all proxies. But nothing.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Well, your error states that `newListItem` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't pass the variable to the template
[image: screenshot of the code]

You should do this instead:

```
res.render("list", { dayWeek: day, newListItem: items });
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it a CORS problem?

On your express server add
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
origin: 'your_client_url:your_client_port'
}));